# Is there a blank theme framework compatible with WP 3.0?

Tags: customization, themes

I don't feel like making my own theme from scratch, so I looked for some theme frameworks, but they're all old and when I install them on WP 3.0 they produce loads of errors and don't behave properly. I just need a 3.0 ready blank theme with the bare elements (just text, but functional) to then shape myself into a good looking blog. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I understand [**Starkers 3.0**](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/starkers-3/) fits the bill. Do you want something [**this naked**](http://starkerstheme.com/demo/), or less?

Comment: Starkers looks good, but the implementation still contains a lot of cruft from Twenty Ten. For example, there's code to handle the custom header. It would be nice if the PHP were cleaned up to match the HTML.

Comment: @Bennett McElwee - heh, no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the [Genesis theme framework](http://www.studiopress.com/) is 3.0 compatible, and utilizes many features such as custom nav menus and featured images. studiopress.com/themes/genesis - it is a premium theme, is supported, and gets regular updates.

Thematic is also 3.0 compatible, if your not looking for a premium theme framework. Check out [themeshaper.com/thematic/](http://themeshaper.com/thematic/)

If you are into the whole BuddyPress thing, check out Buddymattic at [wordpress.org/extend/themes/buddymatic](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/buddymatic)

Comment: Nice suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The new default TwentyTen is always a very start, because it has best support for the new 3.0 theme features.

If you feel more HTML5-y, [Toolbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox) is your theme.

Answer (score 2):

Roots is a blank theme with a lot going for it - HTML5 Boilerplate + Blueprint CSS + more.

http://www.rootstheme.com/

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest the Starkers theme too, it's worth pointing out that Starkers is a stripped back version of the default Twenty 10 theme that comes with WordPress 3. I only mention this as it may be useful to use that as a starting point for WordPress 3.0 site development from the perspective of seeing what the new features are like.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Genesis](http://www.flamescorpion.com/2010/04/how-to-make-your-wordpress-more-website-friendly-with-genesis/) and it was just updated to work with 3.0. It is a framework and you can build child themes on.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that Genesis is worth a look. I also use, and like a lot, [Builder](http://ithemes.com/purchase/builder-theme/) from iThemes.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Thesis](http://diythemes.com/) theme which serves as a framework too and I like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid with [Skeleton child theme](http://themehybrid.com/themes/skeleton) is good combination to make use of framework, but start with minimal design.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to take a look at [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/). Although it's arguably not a bare theme, the idea is to cut it back to what you need. it's only fairly new and certainly works with WP 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Check [Blank Theme](http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/) by Chris Coyier[css-tricks.com].

Answer (score 1):

[WP Basis](http://wpbasis.de/) ist als a theme for this job.